# Cannot Implicitly convert type byte to bool in IF statement

Tags: c#

i have the following code to get the third octet of my IP address

//these are Global Variables declared in a class somewhere

```
public static string HostName = Dns.GetHostName();//get HOSTNAME
public static string myIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(GlobalVars.HostName).AddressList[3].ToString();// Get the IP
public static byte myIP3 = IPAddress.Parse(myIP).GetAddressBytes()[2];//Gets third octet of IP
```

i then want to create an IF statement as follows but receive that error:

```
if (GlobalVars.myIP3= 92){
GlobalVars.Sitecode = "SiteA"
```

}

Comment: Used to VB.NET? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning the value, use a condition `if(GlobalVars.myIP3  ==  92 )`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (GlobalVars.myIP3= 92){
```

is an assignment of the value `92` to the variable `myIP`. The result of an assignement-operation is the assigned value, in your case `92`. However an `if`-statement expects a boolean, which `92` certaintly is not. What you want instead is a *comparison* which is indicated by a doubled `=`:

```
if (GlobalVars.myIP3 == 92){
```